# Trying to reload table containerview after increasing the Stepper count in another containerview

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

Why unexpectedly found nil when trying to reload container view everytime I decrease or increase stepper count? The number of items in the collection view container is based on the stepper value on the settings container view.

```
   rowvalue.text = Int(sender.value).description
    rowcount = Int(sender.value)
    let reloadmimic1 = Mimic1()
    reloadmimic1.mimic1colview.reloadData()
    reloadmimic1.viewWillAppear(true)
```

Comment: In what line do you get that exception? Why don't you assign `rowcount` directly like this: `rowocunt = Int(sender.value)`? Instead you convert it from `String` which is potentially unsafe.

Comment: reloadmimic1.mimic1colview.reloadData() but it supposed to reload the existing loaded data from the api in the container. @kelin

Comment: Don't use UI as a data storage. It's a logical error. UI may change, for example the table cells may be recreated without any text... If you get this error when call `reloadData()` then the `mimic1colview` is probably `nil`.

Comment: It may be `nil` if you call this code before `viewDidLoad()`.

Comment: Then I'll try to centralize the rest api call so that the table cells will be recreated with text @kelin

Comment: I used NSNotificationCenter to do it and it's working without nil crash :) @kelin